# When you adapt a story set in Medieval Europe should you still aim to have a diverse cast even if it's not historically accurate?

Tags: creative-writing, screenwriting

When you adapt a story set in Medieval Europe should you still aim to have a diverse cast even if it's not historically accurate? When you adapt a book set in Medieval Europe, should you still aim to have a diverse cast even if it's not historically or lore accurate? I saw some LOTR adaptations, and they didn't try to be lore-accurate at all and put out a diverse cast. Is this something that's 100% necessary in this day and age, because it seems to me everyone does it.

Comment: If you want to win an [Oscar](https://www.oscars.org/news/academy-establishes-representation-and-inclusion-standards-oscarsr-eligibility), it can't hurt. One important question is whether historical accuracy even matters to the story. If it doesn't, then why not be diverse.

Comment: @towr Quality is more important than awards.

Comment: If you want to be historically accurate, be diverse. There were arabs and africans in europe then. See for example https://www.publicmedievalist.com/uncovering-african/. Just be prepared for people to tell you that you're being inaccurate just for the modern day. The hundred or so years before us are the ones who were being inaccurate for **their** political reasons.

Comment: @KateGregory here lies the problem, just because there were a handful of people who traveled from other parts of the world to Europe does not mean it was a diverse society. Yes there were people of Arabian and  African Decent in Europe but they were nearly as rare as a unicorn in most parts... not the same them making up 50% of the population like some media portrays.

Comment: there are some interesting studies about when people casually think (without counting) a team is 50% minorities -- it's way less than 50% mathematically. For example "our team is almost all women" happens at about 30%. But further discussion of this is probably off topic here. My point remains that an all-white Europe is in fact the "change history for my politics" version of the story, and the OP should feel free to be accurate and have some immigrants and their descendants in the story as the non big deal they were at the time.

Comment: It an odd time we live in which anyone would ask such a question. How can it ever be a good idea to sacrifice historical accuracy for the sake of ideology? It would mean reducing your work to lies and propaganda. There is also the problem that this so called 'diversity' being promoted these days is actually all about reducing diversity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends, on what you want. A good accurate story, or praise from a small but loud group who don't care if a story is good as long as it checks their diversity boxes? And trust me, you won't be able to do it... we live in a time period where a lesbian actress was criticized for not looking lesbian enough while playing a lesbian character or a full blooded Asian actress for not being Asian enough.

The Rings of Power and the new Witcher Spin-off forced diversity and what did it get? horrible reviews... and they will be forgotten in a decade.

Forced diversity is horrible, and if you use a historical setting it's kinda insulting to the region/people it is about. Take the series where they replaced an actual Norse king with a black woman... I have several Norwegian friends who are absolutely disgusted by it.

And personally it feels like rewriting history, people often confuse fiction and reality...and rewriting history to be more ethnically diverse and LGBT acceptance will warp the reality of impressionable people (and if you think people aren't that dumb, after Black Panther thousands of people tried to book a vacation to Wakanda...)

**BUT!**

There are ways to have a relative diverse casting without forcing it. A good example would be [Azeem](https://hero.fandom.com/wiki/Azeem) from Robin Hood. He was a black character in a medieval British setting, but it worked because he and the main character met during the crusades with Azeem chosing to follow the main character to repay a life debt. He was more then a token character and his presence was logically justified.

But the danger is, such a character would be discriminated against heavily in such a period... so that should also be realistic and that can also cause people to lose their minds. For example the movie Blazing Saddles is a movie about a black sheriff in a western setting... back then they were highly discriminated against so that also happens to the main character in the movie (until the people turn around and accept him) but due to the initial bad reactions from the townspeople the movie is banned at certain places for being "triggering".

So in my opinion, **NO** forcing a diverse cast is utter nonsense, but there is nothing wrong with inserting characters of a different ethnicity **IF** it fits the setting. A traveling merchant from the ottoman empire with an Arabic descent for example would be plausible... but a German king who is as black as the night would be stupid. The same goes for LGBT, sure you can have LGBT characters, but then it should fit the setting that they can't be open about it  due to prosecution.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the various definitions of the border between Europe and Asia.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundaries_between_the_continents_of_Earth#Asia_and_Europe

As for The border between Africa and Europe, the mainland north of the Mediterranean was Europe, and the mainland south of it was Africa, and most of the main islands are part of Europe.

The Middle ages lasted from about AD 500 to 1500, or between various other dates suggested, and most sets of dates make them last about 1,000 years - some make them last centuries longer.

And there  are various differences in appearance between people living in different regions of Europe, so that some would seem like strange foreigners if they traveled far in Europe in Medieval times.

In the 7th century AD Arabs from Arabia conquered most of the Middle East and spread into Africa, converting many local people to Islam and enlisting them in their armies.

With decades, they conquered all Northern Africa, and then in 711 invaded Spain and rapidly conquered almost all of it.   The Muslims who came to Spain were mostly Mediterranean type people like the people already living in Spain. Many native people in Spain converted to Islam, so someone couldn't always tell the difference between Muslims and Christians by their looks.

When the Almoravids invaded Spain the 11th and 12th centuries, their armies included  black Africans from south of the Sahara, which may be the reason why the Moors in Spain were often depicted as Black.

I think that all of the major Mediterranean islands of Europe were ruled by Muslims at one time or another, often for centuries.

And in the Late Middle Ages Ottoman Muslims from Turkey invaded Europe and conquered all the Balkans and even beyond, besieging Vienna unsuccessfully in 1529 and 1683.  Many Europeans converted to Islam under Ottoman rule. And some of the Ottomans would have been East Asian in appearances.

Muslims societies had a lot of slavery, so in the slave markets of Muslim ruled parts of Europe there would be slaves, some of which would appear to be Middle Eastern or Mediterranean in appearance, some would be exotic blonde people from the north, and some would be exotic black people from eastern Africa.

Wealthy Muslims had children with slave women of various races, so their descendants didn't always look Arab.  Abd Ar-Rahman III, first Caliph of Cordoba in Spain, had a Christian slave mother, and his father's mother was a Christian princess, so he had ight skin, blue eyes, and light hair, which he dyed black.

In a Muslim family where the mothers had been black slaves for two generations in a row, the family members would end up looking rather black.

Muslim sea raiders often attacked Christian communities on the shores of the Mediterranean. The Vatican in Rome was looted by Muslims in 846. The "Barbary Pirates" from North Africa didn't stop their raids until the 19th century.

Fraxinetum in southern France was was a stronghold of Muslim raiders from about 887-972.  Lundy Island in the Bristol Channel was the base of Moroccans who made slave raids from 1627 to 1632.  Hundreds of Icelanders were killed and captured as slaves by Algerians in the Turkish Raid of 1627.

To be continued with an account of the other main group of exotic foreigners in Europe in the Middle Ages.